# How to adjust text color for Texinfo

Tags: linux, color

I am working with Vim 7.4 on Linux (Xubuntu 14.04). I am editing Texinfo files and I would like to adjust the color of ordinary text. The colors of other items (`@` macros, comments, etc.) are all okay. I just want to change the color of ordinary text.

The color I am seeing for ordinary text is light blue, and I'm thinking it would be easier to read if it were black or maybe green. I looked at texinfo.vim but I wasn't able to see how the color for ordinary text is assigned. I searched the web for hints but I was unable to find something. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Not directly an answer to your question, but start by considering upgrading your machine. 14.04 is more than 7.5 years old now, it's way unsupported at this point. Vim 7.4 is ancient. I'd recommend upgrading to something more modern (ideally one of the latest Ubuntu releases), not just for security updates, but also to get the Vim 8 features.

Comment: You could try modifying the highlight group `Normal`, but if you use one of the various methods to inspect the syntax groups at the places you're interested in, then you will have better luck modifying those

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for the hint, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/36993989/871096 and it's very enlightening. The inferred syntax groups are kind of off the mark. In particular, the syntax group for content text is Identifier! I'll look at texinfo.vim to see if I can puzzle out what's going on there.